How to add a duplicate column to a table?
I am retrieving data from the database using Django ORM:
ws = Ws.objects.all()
ws = ws.filter(*q_objects, **filter_kwargs)
ws = ws.order_by(*sort_list) 
ws = ws.annotate(created_unix=UnixTimestamp(F('created')), date_unix=UnixTimestamp(F('date')))))
total_sum = ws.aggregate(total=Sum('ts_time', output_field=DecimalField()))['total'])['total']
LIST_FIELDS[1], LIST_FIELDS[2] = 'created_unix', 'date_unix'
return JsonResponse({'table_data': list(ws.values_list(*LIST_FIELDS)), 'summ_time': total_sum}, safe=False)    ```    

I need to add a new column to LIST_FIELDS, one that is True for every pair of rows that have multiple fields matching or False
For example:
For LIST_FIELDS[0] and LIST_FIELDS[2]



LIST_FIELDS[0]
LIST_FIELDS[1]
LIST_FIELDS[2]
LIST_FIELDS[3]




1
1
3
True


1
1
2
True


2
1
1
False


1
1
2
True


1
1
3
True



I try ask GPT4, but T9 is stubbornly giving me
ws = ws.annotate(
    match=Case(
        When(field1=F('field2'), then=Value(True)),
        default=Value(False),
        output_field=BooleanField()
    )
)

But it's like comparing field1 == field2 IN ONE row
And I need True, if row1[field1] == row2[field1] and row1[field2] == row2[field2]

So when is it true, if there is another row with identical values?

does the model has a primary key (different from the LIST_FIELDS?

For a given list of columns you want to check for a row with the same values with an Exists subquery [Django-doc]:
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef, Q

UNIQUE_FIELDS = ['created_unix', 'date_unix']

ws = Ws.objects.filter(*q_objects, **filter_kwargs)

ws = Ws.annotate(
    has_duplicate=Exists(
        ws.filter(
            ~Q(pk=OuterRef('pk')), Q(**{k: OuterRef(k) for k in UNIQUE_FIELDS})
        )
    )
)
We thus look for the existence of a Ws object out of ws (so filtered) which has a different primary key (~Q(pk=OuterRef('pk'))), and is the same for the items in the UNIQUE_FIELDS. The field has_duplicate is thus True if another row with the same values for created_unix and date_unix exists in this case.
The response is by the way safe JSON, so you can drop the safe=False, parameter. Sending unsafe JSON is of course not a good idea anyway.
